# link highlight JS library like In-Page Analytics in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, google-analytics, highlight

I want to know a link highlight JavaScript library like In-Page Analytics in Google Analytics.
In In-Page Analytics, every time you hover mouse on the link you see the pink border. I want to implement this function by JavaScript.

What is the name of this link highlighting JavaScript library?
If this is not public library, I want to know similar library or similar browser plugin.

Comment: You mean bubble tooltips?

Comment: No I don't. I mean the pink color border in this twitpic image. http://twitpic.com/cpeivd/full